# Unable to open Google Chrome Portable with Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, portability

Using below code trying to access google chrome portable browser.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\Browsers\\GoogleChromePortable\\GoogleChromePortable.exe");
driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Browser opened but immediately closing with the below exception

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Can anyone help me how to access Google chrome portable browser with Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: the driver  .exe will be something like chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code successfully invoked Google chrome portable browser.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Selenium\\Browsers\\GoogleChromePortable\\GoogleChromePortable.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\Browsers\\chromedriver.exe");              
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Great. Needed to add that set property. This was nice question Aparna.

Comment: @SeJaPy , I tried your method and I'm getting another unknown error this time, "Chrome failed to start: crashed (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)", any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Chromedriver.exe fro running your test cases on Chrome Browser.

```
String ChromeDriverPath= "path\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ChromeDriverPath);
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Chromedriver exe is available at

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Just Extract it and give the path of Chromedriver.exe

Do one thing :

```
Public class processclass{
    Process getBrowserProcess() {
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec("C:\\Selenium\\Browsers\\GoogleChromePortable\\GoogleChrom‌​ePortable.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return p;
    }

}
```

And another class will be containing your test case.
So create a object of the above class let's say :

```
processclass Object = new processclass();

Object.getBrowserProcess();
```

And then run your driver command.

Hope this help you..

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm able to access local installed chrome browser with chromedriver.exe, but need to invoke Chrome Portable browser.  And the exe is  'GoogleChromePortable.exe' , my requirement is to access this exe with selenium webdriver.

Comment: Okay. :-)
Try this
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary(binaryPath);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

Comment: Thanks again, If I'm not wrong, is this the "C:\\Selenium\\Browsers\\GoogleChromePortable\\GoogleChromePortable.exe" binary path?

Comment: Yeah. Whatever exe you are running.

Comment: Tried  following code, ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Selenium\\Browsers\\GoogleChromePortable\\GoogleChromePortable.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); But no luck, getting  exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;"

Comment: But Why you want portable.exe? Cann't You run using chromedriver.exe? Any important thing using portablechrome.exe ?

Comment: Yes, it's client requirement to run application in portable chrome. As a work around what I've done is  able to invoke portable chrome with following java code "Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Selenium\\Browsers\\GoogleChromePortable\\GoogleChromePortable.exe");"  without any issue.  Can you help me  how to attach this existing  browser session with selenium webdriver.

Comment: Thanks Kishan for spending your valuable time to solve this case. Finally got the solution for this issue. Please see answer below.